# Issues with newly added field type in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have added new field type(image) in the existing content type in drupal 7 as shown below

[image]

and tried to access the above added field in the view 
[image]

but I cant able to access the newly added field type. Also it shows reduced number of content types in the drop down. [image]

If I delete the newly added field I can able to access all fields in the drop down. Please help with the solution

Comment: Did you try to clear caches ?

Comment: Yes I have tried with clearing caches but it doesn't work. I have a problem of particularly adding field type image

Comment: Hi on enabling the checkbox of Disable views data caching in views settings clears the above problem. Is this a right way to do this. Please anyone suggest on this.